# Extract file paths and arguments with space from XML as different strings

Tags: c#, xml, split, filepath

I have an XML file which contains some info for starting an application from my exe. Like:

```
<details>
    C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe -env env -direnv direnv
</details>
```

I need to split as the first part for the path for exe and the remaining as arguments. But i get only `C:\Program` when i split by space. IS there another solution to acheive the output as:

> string[0] = C:\Program Files...\abc.exe
>   string[1] = -env env -direnv
>   direnv

Edit code for extracting from XML:

```
XMLNodeLst = GetNodeFromXML().SelectNodes("Path");

if (XMLNodeLst != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in XMLNodeLst)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode pathNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(source, pathNode.Name, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                installPath = pathNode.InnerText.Trim();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                logs.Error("No corresponding value in settings for the provided source name. Please check again!");
                MessageBox.Show("No corresponding value in settings for the provided source name. Please check again!");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Path>
  <details>
    C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe -env env -direnv direnv
  </details>
</Path>
```

To split:

```
string[] configs = installPath.Trim().Split(' ');
exePath = configs[0];
exeArgs = installPath.Remove(0, installPath.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: could you please show your code to read xml and splitting strings?

Comment: Editted in the question

Comment: That value wouldn't work in a command shell either due to the space in Progam Files. Any chance of having `"C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe" -env...` ?

Comment: Try something like this :             string input = @"C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe -env env -direnv direnv";
            string filename = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
            string[] parameters = filename.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string programName = parameters[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might split on a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to assert what is on the left is `.exe` followed by a whitespace and on the right is a dash followed by 1+ non whitespace characters:

`(?<=\.exe) (?=-\S+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5cbyY/1)

```
var installPath = @"C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe -env env -direnv direnv";
string[] configs = Regex.Split(installPath, @"(?<=\.exe) (?=-\S+)");
var exePath = configs[0];
Console.WriteLine(exePath); // C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/hlK4Hf)

Answer (score 0):

Sample of a class which could be used to parse the string:

```
public class ArgumentPathResult {
    public string Path;
    public List<string> Arguments = new List<string>();
}
// Define other methods and classes here
public static class ArgumentPathParser {
    public static ArgumentPathResult ParsePath(string path) {
        ArgumentPathResult result = new ArgumentPathResult();
        string resultString = "";
        foreach(char c in path){
            resultString += c;
            if(resultString.Contains(".exe")){
                break;
            }
        }
        result.Path = resultString;
        result.Arguments = path.Replace(resultString, "")
            .Split('-')
            .Skip(1)
            .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\...\abc.exe -env env -direnv direnv";
ArgumentPathResult result = ArgumentPathParser.ParsePath(path);
```

The result object will contain your Path as one variable, and a list of argument and value pairs `"env env"` and `"direnv direnv"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitted = pathNode.InnerText.Trim()
    .Split(new string[] { ".exe " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var path = splitted[0] + ".exe";
var args = splitted[1];
```